# Cannot overload a generic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What am I doing wrong here:

```
export function fail<a>(problem: SomeProblem): a;
export function fail<a>(message: string): a;
export function fail<a>(messageOrProblem: any): a { throw Error(); }
```

the compiler says:

```
TS2148: Build: Overload signature is not compatible with function definition.
```

Answer (score 6):

The type parameters here are considered 'different' because they come from different places. You should write this like so:

```
export function fail<a>(problem: SomeProblem): a;
export function fail<a>(message: string): a;
export function fail(messageOrProblem: any): any { throw Error(); }
```

As an aside, using a generic type argument only in a return value position is sort of an anti-pattern. Since you have no way to determine what value to return based on `a`, it's much more accurate to return `any` than to return an uninferable generic type. I call this the "moving the cast" pattern:

```
// Bad
x = fail<string>('foo'); // This looks more typesafe than it is
// Good
x = <string>fail('foo'); // Let's be honest with ourselves
```

Comment: good answer! Just a mention, using a return type to drive the generic parameter becomes important in modelling JS promises and allowing automatically inferred `then` chaining